# Movie where a planet (or planet-sized ship) grew from being shot at

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking for a specific movie scene (that i can't recall to which movie it belongs), where the enemy's planet (or it was probably a planet size ship...) kept growing, the more the good guys shot at it.

Any idea?

Comment: We don't do lists here.

Comment: @SeanDuggan Sorry... I'm new here. I'm looking for a scene where the enemies planet grew with the shooting (but any similar would also be fine). I'm editing the question.

Comment: That does look better. I have retracted my close vote.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There is a scene like this in [The Fifth Element](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0119116/).  Near the beginning, a warship approaches the Evil sphere.  They get no readings from it, and the general on board the ship wishes to shoot it.

The president, back on Earth, gives the order, and the general starts firing.  However, instead of destroying the Evil, the Evil gets bigger.  After several vollies, the Evil is several times larger than when it started.  The general's head starts oozing an oil-like substance, and then the Evil attacks, destroys the ship, and continues towards Earth.

Here is a still of the missiles heading towards Evil:
[image]

At 0:58 in the trailer, you see a brief glimpse of the Evil attacking the ship:

Comment: god i love this movie

Comment: It's not blood, but some black, oily substance that oozes from General Staedert's head, as Mr Shadow (the "Evil sphere") grows and draws closer and closer to the ship. The same phenomenon happens to Zorg when he's on the phone with Mr Shadow. The film never explains the phenomenon, but it is implied that Mr Shadow causes it.

Answer (score -1):

Might not help, but there is a scene in the Star Trek: The Next Generation pilot/premiere episode (1x01 - Encounter At Farpoint) where the Enterprise fires on a "city" on the planet that turns out to be a shape-shifting living spaceship.

Comment: This should be a comment